# compute all permutations of a list in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-itertools

I am trying to compute all permutations of a list or column in a df while keeping an id column.

```
input df
    id    list
    1     foo bar
    2     dog cat

desired df output
    id    list
    1     foo bar
    1     bar foo
    2     dog cat
    2     cat dog
```

Comment: Is the value _really_ `'foo bar'`, or is it `['foo', 'bar']`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC just using `permutations` from `itertools`, then it is *unnest*

```
df['list']=df['list'].str.split(' ')
import itertools
df['list']=[list(itertools.permutations(x)) for x in df['list']]
pd.DataFrame({'id':df.id.repeat(df['list'].str.len()),'list':np.concatenate(df['list'].values).tolist()})
Out[522]: 
   id        list
0   1  [foo, bar]
0   1  [bar, foo]
1   2  [dog, cat]
1   2  [cat, dog]
```

Comment: @leo nope you can not :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension with `permutations`:

```
from itertools import permutations

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2], 'list': [['foo', 'bar'], ['cat', 'dog']]})

>>> pd.DataFrame([[id_, list(perm)] 
                  for id_, list_items in df.values for perm in permutations(list_items)], 
                 columns=['id', 'list'])
   id        list
0   1  [foo, bar]
1   1  [bar, foo]
2   2  [cat, dog]
3   2  [dog, cat]
```

Depending on the exact structure of the list contents, you may first need to parse.

Comment: this solution seems to address multiple word counts within the column where the first solution only seems to work with a static word count.

Comment: Wouldn't that make it a better solution to your question? In addition, this solution does not mutate the original dataframe.